# How does one find a non-quadratic residue modulo $p$?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, number-theory

I was wondering how one can find a non-quadratic residue modulo $p$ and what the runtime of this algorithm would be.

I thought that one can use the Legendre Symbol

$$ \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) = a^{ \frac{(p-1)}{2} } \pmod p $$

if the Legendre Symbol returns -1 then its a non quadratic residue and if its a quadratic residue it would return 1. To do this it's easy find a randomized algorithm, since only half the elements are quadratic residues, then one guesses any element at random, say $a \in Z^*_p$ and if the Legendre Symbol returns -1 the return success. Since half the elements are not quadratic residues, it would take about 2 iterations in expectation to find one.

I was wondering, is this algorithm correct? It seems that its completely symmetrical for finding quadratic residues. I am not sure that is strange, but it seems weird to me. Is it correct that the two algorithms are basically the same?

Comment: 1 is always a quadratic residue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are completely right, and your algorithm is a randomized polynomial time algorithm for finding a quadratic non-residue modulo a prime. A major open question in algorithmic number theory is finding a quadratic non-residue *deterministically* in polynomial time. This is possible assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis, but unknown unconditionally. It is also equivalent to extracting square roots modulo a prime. This is all explained in [notes by Booher](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~jeremybooher/expos/sqr_qnr.pdf).

Comment: but it seems that the algorithm for finding Quadratic Residues and Non-residues is the same, just check -1 or +1 instead...is that right?

Comment: Finding a quadratic residue is easier, since 1 is always a quadratic residue.

Comment: oh yea...duh of course 1 is always Quadratic Residue...I guess it only works for QR not equal to 1.